# Sub-typing on Primitive types in Java

Tags: java, primitive, jls, subtype, subtyping

I have this statement in my university classes' notes on sub-typing relations:

> T is a subtype of S if code written for variables of type S can also be safely used on variables of type T

Section 4.10.1 of the [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html), describes the sub-typing relationship amongst primitive types in Java. In particular, I use the fact that `int <: long` i.e `int` is a sub-type of `long` as per the JLS.

So if `int` is a subtype of `long`, then code written for variables of type `long` can also be safely used on variables of type `int`.

This doesn't make sense to me, if I have a piece of code like

```java
long x = 2e63 - 1
```

Then by the statement above, I can use

```java
int x = 2e63 - 1
```

which would obviously lead to overflow.

It seems to me that the second part of the statement should be reversed, i.e "T is a subtype of S if code written for a variable of type T can be safely used on variables of type S". However, in my search for an answer it seems that this statement is repeated in other classes' notes elsewhere. Am I simply misunderstanding it? Maybe the example I gave is not a valid case of the statement?

Comment: To be honest, your uni notes don't make a lot of sense. You should ask your professor to clarify what they meant by "code written for variables of type S can also be safely used on variables of type T", and ask this question to _them_, rather than on Stack Overflow. The JLS is the most authoritative document about the Java language, so you did the right thing here - consult the JLS.

Comment: The uni notes are not precise and only refer to the standard use case of regular classes that extend each other (and also interfaces). So for example if someone wants a `List` you can also give him an `ArrayList` or if someone demands an `Animal` you can give a `Dog` as well.

Comment: Read 4.10.1 of the JLS again closely. They do not state **subtype** relationships but **supertype** relationships between primitives in that section. So `long > int` does hold in this case for your code sample if you think about it with the correct relation.

Comment: @Zabuzard Even for reference types that statement isn't true in general... `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`, but that doesn't mean I can replace the word `Animal` in `Animal a = new Cat();` with `Dog`.

Comment: Also, do not forget about wrapper types. According to the uni notes `int` would be considered subtype of `Integer` since you can do `int value1 = 5; Integer value2 = value1;`. But the JLS does not consider this subtyping at all, just autoboxing.

Comment: @TA They do however say that subtypes are defined by the supertypes. So if `long > int` then `int < long`. (4.10)

Comment: @TA Incorrect, `int <: long` does hold. In §4.10, it specifies that S >1 T implies T <1 S for any types T and S.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll clarify with my professor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if `int` is a subtype of `long`, then code written for variables of type `long` can also be safely used on variables of type `int`.

OK ... I can see how that is a valid characterization of subtyping.

However, this is not how the JLS actually specifies and uses the *subtype relationship* `<:`.  In the JLS, subtyping is primarily about the way that *values* are used.

So, for example, `int <: long` (`int` is a subtype of `long`) means that an `int` value can be used in a context that requires a `long` value.

Here are some examples:

```
 int i = 1;
 long l = i;            // OK - int used where a long is needed
 long ll = i + 1L;      // OK - int used where a long is needed

 public void methodWithLongArg(long arg) { ... }

 methodWithLongArg(i);  // OK - int used where a long is needed
```

Note that in each of the above, the JLS says that the a *primitive widening conversion* is used to convert the `int` value to a `long` value.

So what about your examples:

```
long x = 2e63 - 1;   // NOT OK
int i = 2e63 - 1;    // NOT OK
```

In fact, *neither* of those are legal Java.  The literal `2e63` is a actually a (double) floating point literal.  (All literals that use `e` or `E` notation are floating point, whether or not there is an explicit decimal point in the literal.  And floating point literals without a `f` or `F` suffix denote `double` values.)   So `2e63 - 1` evaluates to a `double` and a `double` cannot be assigned to a `long` (or `int`) unless you explicitly cast it.

That is consistent with the subtyping.  The JLS rules mean that `long <: double`.  So that means that a `long` can be used in a context that requires a `double`.  But in the above, we need a `double` to be used in a context that requires a `long` (or `int`).  And that is the **opposite** of what the subtyping relationships allow.

<sup>In fact, there is another problem with your example.  2<sup>63</sup> is written (in decimal) as `9223372036854775808L`.  And that can only be used if it is preceded by a unary minus operator.  Likewise, it is not expressible as a `long` literal in Java binary, octal or hexadecimal literal syntaxes.</sup>

---

I think that the real problem is that you are misconstruing what your lecturer has said.

What he is *actually* saying is that **code** that has been written for the supertype can be applied to a value of the subtype.

So, in my example, the `methodWithLongArg(long arg)` method is code that been written for the supertype; i.e. `long`.  It can be used (called) on a value of the subtype; i.e. the value of an `int` variable.

> Am I simply misunderstanding it? Maybe the example I gave is not a valid case of the statement?

Basically, yes.  IMO.

Comment: Oops, the `2e63 - 1` was just meant to represent a value outside the range of an `int` but within range of `long`, didn't realise that it's interpreted as a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `int` is a real sub-type of `long` or `double`. They're just the same integer data-type, but each with a different keyword and a different length. Declaring `int <: long` and `long <: double` is required, so that these data-types are known to be lossless cast-able *into one direction*.

[Java byte-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) shows how such primitive data-types are handled behind the scenes. Generally `long` and `double` are nothing but language constructs, because `int` is the data-type being used:

> Note that **any** referenced "value" refers to a 32-bit `int` as per the Java instruction set.

For example: Casting from `int` to `long` is no problem at all, but when casting from `long` to `int`, the binary representation may exceed the digits available to represent the value properly; if the given value is too large, one would need two `int` in order to represent one `long` variable (adding them together by their binary complement won't yield the same value, as it would have to be split into two sets of bits). Look at their binary representations ...those should make the topic obvious.